# Publish to Azure, cannot access image files

Tags: azure, .net-core

I published my site to Azure, but I keep getting a filenotfound error:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\Images\picture.jpg'.
```

I checked via FTP and the directories and pictures are there, in the correct directory. What did I do wrong then? It works just fine locally, and the picturen are all on the Azure server

Comment: you should use virtual path: "~/Images/picture.jpg"

Comment: I've added "~/" to all of the strings but still get the same error: FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\~\Images\picture.jpg'.

Comment: try removing the '~` then just use `/Images/picture.jpg'